# Why removing orphan functions will not help size of my statically linked file

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, static-libraries, static-linking

Let's consider this minimal example:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile it dynamically linked:

```
gcc main.c -o dl_out
```

and once with static linking:

```
gcc -static main.c -o sl_out
```

Now, having a look at the sizes:

```
ls -hl sl_out dl_out

-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  17K Nov 29 20:50 dl_out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 852K Nov 29 20:50 sl_out
```

It is not actually surprising to me because static linking will load a huge amount of unnecessary functions to the application. But, what surprises me is how come my best effort to remove those unused functions will not lead to any significant size reduction.

I have removed unused functions:

```
gcc -static -Os -fvisibility=hidden -fwhole-program -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -flto -s main.c -o sl_out2 -Wl,--gc-sections -W
```

But, when checking over the sizes, the result is not that good:

```
ls -hl sl_out dl_out sl_out2

-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  17K Nov 29 20:50 dl_out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 852K Nov 29 20:50 sl_out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 756K Nov 29 20:57 sl_out2
```

> Reminder note: dl_out is dynamically linked, sl_out is statically linked, sl_out2 is optimized statically linked

I was expecting much size reduction because at the end, this `printf` is equivalent to a `puts` which is written to a `stdout` file descriptor by a `syscall` and it does not really need such a huge size. Where am I making mistake? And is there any way to achieve what I want while still using static linking?

---

**Update**

The `.text` section is really big:

```
readelf -SW sl_out2

There are 28 section headers, starting at offset 0xbc6e8:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .note.gnu.property NOTE            0000000000400270 000270 000020 00   A  0   0  8
  [ 2] .note.gnu.build-id NOTE            0000000000400290 000290 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            00000000004002b4 0002b4 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .rela.plt         RELA            00000000004002d8 0002d8 000240 18  AI  0  19  8
  [ 5] .init             PROGBITS        0000000000401000 001000 00001b 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 6] .plt              PROGBITS        0000000000401020 001020 000180 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 7] .text             PROGBITS        00000000004011a0 0011a0 08ec80 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 8] .fini             PROGBITS        000000000048fe20 08fe20 00000d 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 9] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000000000490000 090000 01b7ac 00   A  0   0 32
  [10] .stapsdt.base     PROGBITS        00000000004ab7ac 0ab7ac 000001 00   A  0   0  1
  [11] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        00000000004ab7b0 0ab7b0 009e94 00   A  0   0  8
  [12] .gcc_except_table PROGBITS        00000000004b5644 0b5644 0000c4 00   A  0   0  1
  [13] .tdata            PROGBITS        00000000004b7320 0b6320 000020 00 WAT  0   0  8
  [14] .tbss             NOBITS          00000000004b7340 0b6340 000040 00 WAT  0   0  8
  [15] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      00000000004b7340 0b6340 000010 08  WA  0   0  8
  [16] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      00000000004b7350 0b6350 000010 08  WA  0   0  8
  [17] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS        00000000004b7360 0b6360 002bf4 00  WA  0   0 32
  [18] .got              PROGBITS        00000000004b9f58 0b8f58 000090 00  WA  0   0  8
  [19] .got.plt          PROGBITS        00000000004ba000 0b9000 0000d8 08  WA  0   0  8
  [20] .data             PROGBITS        00000000004ba0e0 0b90e0 001a10 00  WA  0   0 32
  [21] __libc_IO_vtables PROGBITS        00000000004bbb00 0bab00 0006a8 00  WA  0   0 32
  [22] __libc_atexit     PROGBITS        00000000004bc1a8 0bb1a8 000008 00  WA  0   0  8
  [23] .bss              NOBITS          00000000004bc1c0 0bb1b0 0015c8 00  WA  0   0 32
  [24] __libc_freeres_ptrs NOBITS          00000000004bd788 0bb1b0 000028 00  WA  0   0  8
  [25] .comment          PROGBITS        0000000000000000 0bb1b0 00002b 01  MS  0   0  1
  [26] .note.stapsdt     NOTE            0000000000000000 0bb1dc 0013e8 00      0   0  4
  [27] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 0bc5c4 000123 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  l (large), p (processor specific)
```

and

```
readelf -lW sl_out2

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x401be0
There are 10 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x000518 0x000518 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000401000 0x0000000000401000 0x08ee2d 0x08ee2d R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x090000 0x0000000000490000 0x0000000000490000 0x025708 0x025708 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x0b6320 0x00000000004b7320 0x00000000004b7320 0x004e90 0x006490 RW  0x1000
  NOTE           0x000270 0x0000000000400270 0x0000000000400270 0x000020 0x000020 R   0x8
  NOTE           0x000290 0x0000000000400290 0x0000000000400290 0x000044 0x000044 R   0x4
  TLS            0x0b6320 0x00000000004b7320 0x00000000004b7320 0x000020 0x000060 R   0x8
  GNU_PROPERTY   0x000270 0x0000000000400270 0x0000000000400270 0x000020 0x000020 R   0x8
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0b6320 0x00000000004b7320 0x00000000004b7320 0x002ce0 0x002ce0 R   0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .note.gnu.property .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag .rela.plt 
   01     .init .plt .text .fini 
   02     .rodata .stapsdt.base .eh_frame .gcc_except_table 
   03     .tdata .init_array .fini_array .data.rel.ro .got .got.plt .data __libc_IO_vtables __libc_atexit .bss __libc_freeres_ptrs 
   04     .note.gnu.property 
   05     .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag 
   06     .tdata .tbss 
   07     .note.gnu.property 
   08     
   09     .tdata .init_array .fini_array .data.rel.ro .got
```

If you are curious what are the codes about, what I see via Ghidra is massive functions with internal names:

[image: Ghidra static linked application]

---

**Update 2**

If you think the `printf` is heavy, try with `puts`. You get the same result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("Hello World2");
    // printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and there we go:

```
gcc -static -Os -fvisibility=hidden -fwhole-program -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -flto -s main.c -o sl_out2 -Wl,--gc-sections -W

./sl_out2
Hello World2

ls -lh ./sl_out2
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 756K Nov 29 22:01 ./sl_out2
```

The size `756K` is still huge compare to dynamic linking. Come on, `puts` cannot be that heavy.

---

**Note:** This question is not about why the static linking has a bigger size. It is about why the options to eliminate dead-codes cannot help. I am looking for a compiler option or an external conventional tool (commonly used) to really eliminate the dead-code.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250001/discussion-on-question-by-ar2015-why-removing-orphan-functions-will-not-help-siz).